# Getting Message Count of a JMS queue Programmatically using any API

Tags: java, jboss, jms

I have created a queue in JBoss 5 with persistence. Messages are consumed asynchronously so what I want is the count of messages already in the queue every time a server is restarted. I can see the message count on jmx-console (Screenshot Attached). This message count i want in my program.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/690cT.png)

Comment: Just use JMX to do that

Comment: Can you refer an example ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a QueueBrowser to view messages that are in the queue. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html

Comment: Sorry for the above comment.. actually there was my mistake .. i have initialised the queue listener first , hence there was nothing in queue .. thanks for the help dude..

Answer (score 4):

You can try with jmx as @konstantin-v-salikhov suggest.

From same jvm (eg from a war):

```
MBeanServerConnection mbeanServer = MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss();
ObjectName queue = new ObjectName ("jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=testQueue" );  
Integer messageCount = (Integer)server.getAttribute ( queue, "MessageCount" );  
System.out.println ( messageCount );
```

Remote access:

```
Hashtable<String,String> ht=new Hashtable<String,String>();
ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory");
ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"localhost:1099");
ht.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"admin");
ht.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"admin");

Context context = new InitialContext(ht);

MBeanServerConnection mbeanServer = (MBeanServerConnection)context.lookup ( "jmx/invoker/RMIAdaptor" );  
ObjectName queue = new ObjectName ("jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=testQueue" );  
Integer messageCount = (Integer)server.getAttribute ( queue, "MessageCount" );  
System.out.println ( messageCount );
```

Comment: I tried your solution given above for same JVM but it is throwing an exception 

javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=testQueue

at line 2 .

Can you help to resolve it ??

Comment: You must use the correct object name, in your case `jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=AuthMailQueue` see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/ObjectName.html